# how to include HTML form method=DELETE for the same "action" in the REST service call

Tags: javascript, html, rest

I want to include DELETE method in the same HTML form, calling the same action(calling a REST service) . How do I do this ? . My current HTML form looks like this :, the DELETE functionality does not work , but the POST does. I have included the REST resource service as well. Any suggestions is appreciated.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Form to create a new resource</title>
  <style>
    tab { padding-left: 4em; }
    </style>
 </head>
<body>

 <form id= "myForm" action="../com.dcr.jersey.first/rest/todos" >

  <label for="id">ID</label>
  <input name="id" />
  <br/>
  <label for="summary">Summary</label>
  <input name="summary" />
  <br/>
  Description:
  <TEXTAREA NAME="description" COLS=40 ROWS=6></TEXTAREA>
  <br/> 
  <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>  <tab> <button type="submit" value="Delete">Delete</button>
  <script>
      $("button.Submit").click(function(){
            $("#myForm").attr("method", "POST");
        });

        $("button.delete").click(function(){
            $("#myForm").attr("method", "DELETE");
        });
  </script>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

TodosResource.java

```
package com.dcr.jersey.jaxb.resources;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Request;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

import com.dcr.jersey.jaxb.dao.TodoDao;
import com.dcr.jersey.jaxb.model.Todo;
//Will map the resource to the URL todos
@Path("/todos")
public class TodosResource {

    // Allows to insert contextual objects into the class,
      // e.g. ServletContext, Request, Response, UriInfo
      @Context
      UriInfo uriInfo;
      @Context
      Request request;
      @Context
      Todo todo;
    // Return the list of todos to the user in the browser
      @GET
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
      public List<Todo> getTodosBrowser() {
        List<Todo> todos = new ArrayList<Todo>();
        todos.addAll(TodoDao.instance.getModel().values());
        return todos;
      }
    // Return the list of todos for applications
      @GET
      @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
      public List<Todo> getTodos() {
        List<Todo> todos = new ArrayList<Todo>();
        todos.addAll(TodoDao.instance.getModel().values());
        return todos;
      }
    // retuns the number of todos
      // Use http://localhost:8080/de.vogella.jersey.todo/rest/todos/count
      // to get the total number of records
      @GET
      @Path("count")
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
      public String getCount() {
        int count = TodoDao.instance.getModel().size();
        return String.valueOf(count);
      }

      @POST
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
      @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
      public void newTodo(@FormParam("id") String id,
          @FormParam("summary") String summary,
          @FormParam("description") String description,
          @Context HttpServletResponse servletResponse) throws IOException {
        Todo todo = new Todo(id, summary);
        if (description != null) {
          todo.setDescription(description);
        }
        TodoDao.instance.getModel().put(id, todo);
        servletResponse.sendRedirect("../Created_PopUp.html");
      }  

      @POST
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
      @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})

      public void newTodoXMLJSON(Todo todo) throws IOException {
        this.todo=todo;
        TodoDao.instance.getModel().put(todo.getId(), todo);
      }  

      @DELETE
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
      @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
      public void delTodo(@FormParam("id") String id,
          @Context HttpServletResponse servletResponse) throws IOException {
          Todo c = TodoDao.instance.getModel().remove(id);
            if(c==null)
              throw new RuntimeException("Delete: Todo with " + id +  " not found");
            else servletResponse.sendRedirect("../create_todo.html");
      }  

      @Path("{todo}")
      public TodoResource getTodo(@PathParam("todo") String id) {
            return new TodoResource(uriInfo, request, id);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

isn't the property called "formmethod" and not method. The method attribute is usually at the form level. Try 
`$("#myForm").attr("formmethod", "POST");`
instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use only one method (attributes are unique) on a form.

A workaround would be changing the form method depending on what button you press.

JQ Ex:

```
$("button.save").click(function(){
    $("#myForm").attr("method", "POST");
});

$("button.delete").click(function(){
    $("#myForm").attr("method", "DELETE");
});
```

Also take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8790663/157768) for info on browser support.

Comment: I updated the html as you suggested , it still does not work. I updated the HTML script in the post( as you suggested ) using the `<script>` tags, is this how we have to insert the script in HTML ?

Answer (score 0):

*HTML* forms support only `GET` and `POST` methods, if you want to use other methods like `DELETE`, `PUT` or `PATCH` you should send them using `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest`.